How to optimize a query
I have the following query that might be taking a long time.
SELECT b.*, ubh.bookId, ubh.position, ubh.completedDate, ubh.userId  
FROM user_book_history AS ubh 
INNER JOIN books AS b ON ubh.bookId = b.id 
WHERE ubh.userId = ? ORDER by ubh.createDate desc

What can I do to optimize this query? What indices should I add to the mysql table? Can someone help?
CREATE TABLE "user_book_history" (
  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "bookId" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "userId" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "position" int DEFAULT '0',
  "createDate" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  "completedDate" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);


CREATE TABLE "books" (
  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "amazonBuyUrl" text,
  "audioUrl" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "author" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "authorDesc" text,
  "body" longtext,
  "categories" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "description" text,
  "image" text,
  "publishDate" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  "subtitle" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "title" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "uploadDate" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  "video" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "mediaUrl" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "subid" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "tags" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "free" tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  "infographicUrl" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "vector" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "comingSoon" tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  "isPopular" tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

I attached the EXPLAIN output and the create tables


Without schema information, we can only guess what is happening.  Best way to show us your data is to : Create an SQL fiddle from one of the many sql fiddle sites.  Use MySQL's "show create table" to describe the tables for books and user_book_history.  Put that in the fiddle's DDL along with some test data.

Failing that you can show us the EXPLAIN  for your SELECT but that's not as good as providing schema information

This is a simple sorted join.  Unless there are many millions of records, this shouldn't be lengthy.  What does "taking a long time" mean to you?

@erik258 I attached the explain and create tables.

This should optimize the lookup for the specific userId, and the sorting by createDate, and the reference to bookId for the join:
ALTER TABLE user_book_history
  ADD INDEX (userId, createDate);

This does not achieve the covering-index optimization, because your query references other columns.
books.id is the primary key for that table. Your EXPLAIN shows that the join is optimized already as an eq_ref access. There is nothing more you need to do for that table.
After applying this index, I tested with EXPLAIN and I see this:
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ubh   | NULL       | ref    | userId        | userId  | 5       | const           |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Backward index scan |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.ubh.bookId |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                             |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------+

This shows the new index on (userId, createdDate) is used, which turns type: ALL into type: ref (lookup on a non-unique index), and the "Using filesort" is eliminated.
The access to the books table is still by primary key, which is as good as you can get.

Quick question, shouldn't the index be (bookId, userId, createDate) ? I have no data to test it, but in the fiddle it shows the same execution plan demo

@ErgestBasha The plan is the same because in both cases it chose the index that starts with userId.

My bad, the long hours are doing their jobs

Look how easy it was to discuss Ergest Basha's comment with the supplied fiddle, Chris Hansen.  That is the best way to make answering your question easy and effective
